# Struggling with collision detection. How do I detect the collision correctly?

Tags: c++, sfml, collision, shapes

```
class ShapePlanet
{
public:
    sf::CircleShape shape;
    sf::Vector2f planetposition;
    int radius = 45;
    ShapePlanet()
    {
        float x = rand() % 1020; //invece che 1280
        float y = rand() % 650; //invece che 720
        this->shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
        this->planetposition.x = x;
        this->planetposition.y = y;
        this->shape.setPosition(x, y);
    }
};

struct Node_Planet
{
    ShapePlanet Planet;
    Node_Planet* next;
};
typedef Node_Planet* ptr_list;

class Planet
{
private:
    ptr_list head;
public:
    ptr_list create(int n)
    {
        ptr_list tmp = NULL;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i = i + 1)
        {
            {
                tmp = new Node_Planet;
                tmp->Planet = ShapePlanet();
                tmp->next = head;
                head = tmp;
            }
            return this->head;
        }


        void draw(sf::RenderWindow& window)
        {
            ptr_list p = this->head;
            while (p != NULL)
            {
                window.draw(p->Planet.shape);
                p = p->next;
            }
        }

        void IsItOverLapped()
        {
            ptr_list p1 = this->head;
            ptr_list p2 = this->head;
            // bool collision = false;
            sf::FloatRect shape1;
            sf::FloatRect shape2;
            float distance;
            float dx;
            float dy;
            //float distance = std::sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));

            while ((p1 != NULL))
            {
                //float distance = std::sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));
                while (p2 != NULL)
                {
                    shape1 = p1->Planet.shape.getGlobalBounds();
                    shape2 = p2->Planet.shape.getLocalBounds();
                    dx = (p1->Planet.shape.getPosition().x + (shape1.width / 2)) - (p2->Planet.shape.getPosition().x + (shape2.width / 2));
                    dy = (p1->Planet.shape.getPosition().y + (shape1.height / 2)) - (p2->Planet.shape.getPosition().y + (shape2.height / 2));
                    distance = std::sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));
                    if (distance <= (shape1.width / 2) + (shape2.width / 2))
                    //if (p2->Planet.shape.getGlobalBounds().intersects(p1->Planet.shape.getLocalBounds()))
                    {
                        std::cout << "Collision Detected" << std::endl;
                        //p2 = p2->next;
                        //collision = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        std::cout << "No Collision Detected" << std::endl;
                        //collision = false;
                    }
                    /*if (p2->Planet.shape.getLocalBounds().intersects(p1->Planet.shape.getLocalBounds()))
                        std::cout << "collision";
                        std::cout <<'\n'; */
                    p2 = p2->next;
                }
                p1 = p1->next;
            }
            //return collision;
        }
    }
};
```

So, I would like to be able to draw the shapes on the screen. The problem is that I struggle with the detection of collision of the shapes. If I am able to detect the collision, then I can change the position of the overlapped shape. But I am struggling with it a lot. 
I have a list of objects. And they have some charateristics as the shape, the position etc. 
I have tried also to use the if(object1.getLocalBounds.intersects(object2.getLocalbounds()) {then do something} but seems the code doesn't go in the if side. I have tried a lot of times and I really don't know how to handle this thing anymore.

Comment: Please don't typedef pointers! That's just a bad habit coming from MS and serves for nothing but information hiding...

Comment: If you consider *round* planets, then I wouldn't intersect rectangles, instead, you might calculate the distance of their centers, you get an intersection if this distance is smaller than the sum of the two radii...

Comment: Our professor always does it.

Comment: I tried with the calculation of distance and doing the radius thing, but I have failed in that case too. I looked up on internet trying to find something, and I found that code but still not getting anywhere :/

Comment: Well, it's not uncommon that professors follow bad habits. They are profess*or*s, not profess*ional*s (in sense of developers; I admit that they are professional teachers)...

Comment: Distance calculation is rather simple: `double dx = p0.x - p1.x, dy = p0.y - p1.y; double distance = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);`

Comment: Will try again and see if I can adjust it. Thanks for the patience.

Comment: I have tried to create just a function that prints when the shapes are overlapped but still doesn't work in the way I would like to, I have tried to use the formula you posted here :/

Comment: Cannot tell much without seeing the concrete code; but at it is totally different one, you might rather post a new question (you could leave a link here in the comments to make it easier to find).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57595557/still-struggling-with-the-detection-of-collision-of-shapes

Comment: See my comments on your [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57595557/5910058).

Comment: As C++, you should prefer *keywords* (`nullptr`) over old (obsolete?) C *macros* (`NULL`).

Answer (score 3):

First, you should not build your own data structures (such as `ptr_list`) unless you have a very good reason to (or, if you're writing the code explicitly to learn about pointers and data structures, but then maybe don't mix it with collision). Instead, use the [STL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) -- already one thing less you have to worry about. Also [avoid `new` and `delete`](http://bromeon.ch/articles/raii.html).

Next, make sure you understand the SFML functions you're using. `getLocalRect()` and `getGlobalRect()` return you rectangles in two different coordinate systems, you can't just add/subtract them and expect a meaningful result. Consult the SFML documentation for more clarity. Plus, you should use directly `sf::Rect::intersects()` instead of building your own.

What you need to consider is that SFML will do an intersection check of *axis-aligned bounding boxes*, and **not** check if the actual rectangles intersect. This is simpler and faster than correct rectangle check, however less accurate. I would start with axis-aligned rectangles and then take it from there.

What could also help is to separate the code that checks for overlaps (*collision detection*) and the code that reacts to it (*collision response*). The first one would be a simple bool function that doesn't modify any state, and the second then performs the necessary actions.

Comment: Thank you for the response. And yes I have good reason to, because this is how I have learnt to do things in school and I don't know other ways to handle it. And I prefer working with my own data structures than handling some libraries and not understanding where I am going to. And about the getLocalrect, i have to admit I have copied those codes from a guy on youtube where he showed how to do the detection of collision. I was trying with another way but that wasn't working :/

Comment: "And I prefer working with my own data structures than handling some libraries and not understanding where I am going to" -- well, the point is that you _learn_ how to use those libraries ;) you will notice soon that they support you massively. The STL has been thoroughly tested and is applicable to a wide range of problems, it also takes care of memory management and provides algorithms for finding, sorting, filtering and much more. Why would you reinvent the wheel for basic C++ functionality if you could spend that time on developing a game?

Answer (score 0):

```
p1 = head;
p2 = head;

while (p1)
{
    while (p2)
    {
        // ...
        p2 = p2->next;
    }
    (*)
    p1 = p1->next;
}
```

When the code reaches `(*)` the first time, p2 was set to `nullptr` in the inner loop; but as you don't reset it within inner loop, it will remain there for all other loop runs, thus comparing second planet in the list against none of the others any more.

Additionally, as you initially set both pointers to head, you'll compare very first planet against itself, naturally resulting in a collision.

The fix for both issues:

```
p1 = head;
while (p1)
{
    p2 = p1->next;
    //       ^ avoid self-comparison
    while (p2)
    {
        // ...
        p2 = p2->next;
    }
    p1 = p1->next;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! Can't believe that for this thing:   p2 = p1->next; I was doing the code. Thank you very much! Really!